# EaselJS - performance problems

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I'm implementing a simple racing game with easelJS library. This is my 1st experience with it, so I might be doing something wrong. Moving of my sprite is not smooth despite 60fps and `createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF;`

Let me paste some part of my code.
`game.js`

```
function init() {
  keys = new Keys();

  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
  stage.mouseEventsEnabled = true;
  stage.mouseMoveOutside = false;

  // Maximise the canvas
  canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
  canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;

  localPlayer = new Bike();
  localPlayer.init();

  setEventHandlers();
}

function setEventHandlers() {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeydown, false);
  window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyup, false);
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);
  createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF;
}

function tick() {
  if (localPlayer.getSprite()) localPlayer.update();
  stage.update();
}
```

`Keys` is just a class which handle arrow up press up and down.
`Bike` is an motorbike class responsible for updating and drawing the spritesheet.

`bike.js`

...

```
  function init() {
    img.onload = handleImageLoad;
    img.src = '/img/bikeSprite.png';
  }

  function handleImageLoad() {
    var spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
      // image to use
      images: [img],
      // width, height & registration point of each sprite
      frames: {
        width: 42,
        height: 42,
        regX: 21,
        regY: 21
      }
    });

    sprite = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet);
    sprite.regX = sprite.spriteSheet.frameWidth / 2 | 0;
    sprite.regY = sprite.spriteSheet.frameHeight / 2 | 0;
    sprite.gotoAndStop(BIKE_START_FRAME);

    sprite.x = (CANVAS_WIDTH / 2) - 20;
    sprite.y = (CANVAS_HEIGHT / 2) + (GRASS_HEIGHT / 2) + 50;
    stage.addChild(sprite);
  }
```

and then my main update method:

```
function update() {
    clutch = keys.action ? true : false;

    // Thrust can happen only if clutch is not present.
    thrust = (!clutch && keys.up) ? true : false;

    // Turning
    if (keys.left) angleVel = -TURN_ANGLE;
    if (keys.right) angleVel = TURN_ANGLE;

    if (!keys.left && !keys.right) angleVel = 0;

    // Custom animation
    if (sprite && (!keys.left || !keys.right)) sprite.stop();

    velXY[0] *= (1 - friction);
    velXY[1] *= (1 - friction);

    angle += angleVel;

    if (angle >= MAX_ANGLE || angle <= -MAX_ANGLE) {
      angle = 0;
    }

    forward = angleToVector(angle);

    if (thrust) {
      if (angleVel === 0) {
        velXY[0] += forward[0] * SPEED * ACC * clutchFactor;
        velXY[1] += forward[1] * SPEED * ACC * clutchFactor;
      } else {
        velXY[0] += forward[0] * SPEED;
        velXY[1] += forward[1] * SPEED;
      }
    }

    if(keys.up && clutch) {
      if (clutchFactor < MAX_CLUTCH) {
        clutchFactor += 0.1;
      }
    } else {
      if (clutchFactor > MIN_CLUTCH) {
        clutchFactor -= 0.1;
      }
    }

    sprite.x += velXY[0];
    sprite.y += velXY[1];

    velocity = Math.sqrt((velXY[0] * velXY[0]) + (velXY[1] * velXY[1]));
    velocity = parseFloat(velocity).toFixed(2);

    if (sprite.x > canvas.width) {
      sprite.x = sprite.x % canvas.width;
    } else if (sprite.x < 0) {
      sprite.x = canvas.width + (sprite.x % canvas.width);
    }

    if (sprite.y > canvas.height) {
      sprite.y = sprite.y % canvas.height;
    } else if (sprite.y < 0) {
      sprite.y = canvas.height + (sprite.y % canvas.height);
    }

    if (keys.left) {
      if (leftOffset >= TURN_OFFSET) {
        leftOffset = 0;
        sprite.reverse();
      } else {
        leftOffset++;
      }
    }

    if (keys.right) {
      if (rightOffset >= TURN_OFFSET) {
        rightOffset = 0;
        sprite.forward();
      } else {
        rightOffset++;
      }
    }
  }
```

These are my globals:

```
var canvas
  , stage
  , keys
  , track
  , localPlayer = {};
```

I also have custom methods `reverse` and `forward`:

```
createjs.Sprite.prototype.reverse = function() {
    var currentFrame = this._currentFrame
        , numFrames = this.spriteSheet.getNumFrames(this.currentAnimation);

    if (currentFrame <= 0) {
        currentFrame = numFrames - 1;
    } else {
        currentFrame--;
    }

    this.gotoAndStop(currentFrame);
};

createjs.Sprite.prototype.forward = function() {
    var currentFrame = this._currentFrame
        , numFrames = this.spriteSheet.getNumFrames(this.currentAnimation);

    if (currentFrame >= numFrames) {
        currentFrame = 0;
    } else {
        currentFrame++;
    }

    this.gotoAndStop(currentFrame);
};
```

My current app can be tested here:
https://speedwayjs.herokuapp.com/
As you can see its not super smooth.

Comment: Line 11 in your game.js: `console.log(rect1, rect2);`. Might not be the only performance eater, but certainly one of them.

Comment: Removed it, but still not super smooth. I wonder if that might be a sprite issue.

Comment: Ok, found some more room for improvement: 1. Get rid of jQuery, at least in functions that are called often. [Here's why](https://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-javascript-performance-comparison/22). 2. Store the values that you need often (namely the DOM nodes you fetch in `log()` - fetch them once, assign them to a variable, and use the variable.) 3. You re-draw the entire background in every single frame, right? Since it doesn't actually change, I suggest using a background image on the `<canvas>` element instead (if that even works, otherwise do it on a parent element).

Comment: I removed temporarly log method and the track itself. But I can't see much difference. Its working fine on OSX and chrome. But on Windows and chrome still a bit laggy.

Comment: I just realized you use the `tick` function to handle user interaction *and* re-draw the canvas. This is bad for multiple reasons: 1. If the frame rate is higher, the entire game will run faster. That does not seem right. 2. Doing calculations in the function that's supposed to draw will consume time, which will reduce smoothness. Particularly in `requestAnimationFrame` mode, you should really only do drawing. So split the calculations from the drawing and run the drawing in the current tick function, and the calculations on `setInterval(..., 100/3)` or so.

Comment: I moved as suggested. But not sure if there is any improvement. You can see the WIP code here https://github.com/jakubsikora/speedway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80756/discussion-between-deboer-and-siguza).